# LogCat errors and what they mean

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, logcat

Okay so i did a tutorial on building my first app and once i was finished i tried running it on the emulator in eclipse and i got a "unfortunately your app has stopped" message. i then tried on my actual android device and got the same message. I viewed my LogCat and found these errors but im not that competent yet in this process.

Here is the LogCat,

```
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015): Process: com.dummies.android.helloandroid, PID: 2015
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dummies.android.helloandroid/com.dummies.android.helloandroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:110)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at com.dummies.android.helloandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     ... 11 more
```

Please if anyone can help with some explanations as to what these mean that would be great.

Thank you

Comment: The first thing I usually do when I get an error is scroll to the bottom of the logcat, and then start moving up until I find a line that says something like `07-08 12:58:53.739: E/AndroidRuntime(2015): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.` in your logcat post. I look for this because of the `Caused by: ` portion; this tells me that the line following the declaration is likely the cause of my problems.

Comment: @greg-449 What about all of these other errors? have you any clue as to what they mean?

Comment: What you have is essentially a Java 'Stack Trace' giving you the details about exactly what was happening when the error occurred - there is only one error in this trace and it is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity`

Comment: and it seems that the error is on the oncreate method... in the main activity... in line number 12... can you please post that peace of code...!! regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set your theme correctly in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Taken from the [dev docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme):

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

And that you have added the application compatibillity library and choose one of those themes that are included. For example you can try and use the theme:
`Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` or make your custom theme use that as parent depending on your layout and design.

Comment: @geekcode  here is line 12   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: how do i add the libraries? @Niclas

Comment: From the stacktrace it looks like you are using the ActionBar in the compat library, and I'm guessing you have created your project via an "ide template" via eclipse or intellij. If that is true you probably already have the dependencies via gradle or ant. Try to add the theme in your androidmanifest.xml.

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library out to be sure. If/when the library is setup you should be able to use Theme.AppCompat as theme in you androidmanifest.xml

Comment: so I set up my support library and now how do I input the Theme.App.compact in the android manifest.xml ? @Niclas